# How to bind DataGrid with some dynamic columns, some static?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have ran in to a problem with a WPF DataGrid that I don't really know how to approach. The thing is that I currently have a DataGrid which is bound to a StaticResource. This resource is a CollectionViewSource bound to an ObservableCollection property in my view model. (The reason for the CollectionViewSource is to define sort-order for the grid in XAML code.) The columns in the DataGrid are "static", in the sense that i have `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` and define the columns manually in XAML. Some columns are calculated using converters. This is all working fine at the moment.

But now I have a requirement that in the middle of the existing, "static", columns in the grid I should add an undefined number of "dynamic" columns and the number of columns actually depend on the data bound to the grid.

Let's say for example that I have a row in the grid that represents a salesperson at a company. For every salesperson there are some "static" columns in the grid that displys e.g. stuff like age, salary, shoe size etc. There are also different types of sales persons, let's say type A and B. If I select type A in a drop-down in the GUI the grid should also display columns for which sales areas each person is responsible for. Type A sales persons could be (but don't have to be) responsible for areas 1, 2 and 3. Type B sales persons could be responsible for areas 6, 7, 8 and 9. So for each type chosen, the grid should display columns for each area and fill the cell if the person is actually resposible for that area.

I hope this simple example makes sense. So how would I go about introducing this into my existing DataGrid?

Comment: The "dynamic" columns - do they map to existing properties etc on the type? or are they computed somehow? if the latter, sounds like `ITypedList`

Comment: Well, yes, in a sense. The data for the cell is available in the type, i.e. in my example it would be what areas each person is actually responsible for. But that could differ from which areas/columns should be shown, and that is not directly available. I need to take a look at what ITypedList does, thanks for the hint.